# Decoding HTML Entities using Bottle for Python

Tags: python, html, bottle

So basically I am writing a web application using [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/) for Python. But I have run into a very weird and frustrating bug: Whenever I try to put any HTML code via the code, it converts them to HTML entities. Here, its better I let the code explain:

```
def fillFlist():
    files = os.listdir('Files/FS/')
    tFlist = []
    for item in files:
        tFlist.append('<tr><td>')
        tFlist.append(item)
        tFlist.append('</td><td>')
        tFlist.append('<a href="localhost/delete/' + item + '">Delete</a></td></tr>')
    tempO = ''
    tempI = tempO.join(tFlist)
    print(tempI)
    return tempI
```

That there is basically a system that will loop through the files and create a table row for each file, and also add a link to delete the file. Then you can see the joining the table to make one string, and then this string would be inserted into the HTML to create a table, but instead of a nice table, I end up with this:

```
<tr><td>test.txt</td><td><a href="localhost/delete/hello.txt">Delete</a></td></tr>
```

Straight and raw on the page. I have googled forever trying to figure this problem out, but have yielded nothing. Some additional notes to help you out:

```
Cookie = request.get_cookie('uploaded')
Flist = fillFlist()

return template(loadHTML('index.html'), flist=Flist, cookie=Cookie)
```

This is basically is whats meant to insert the table into the HTML file, by doing this:

```
{{flist}}
```

And basically, I put that anywhere in the HTML code, and the template above requires a string to put in its place, and so whenever the page is loaded, whatever is in that string, is placed where ever the {{varname}} is.

Good Luck and Thankyou in advance!

Edit 1:

I have also found out that it is not being converted in my code at all, so it gets converted right as its put on the web page? I don't know, and I guess, that's why i'm here.

Edit 2:

Well I fixed the problem, turns out when I parse lines of HTML code through to the web page (using the {{varname}} method), it converts the special characters into entities. So after a whole day slaving over the keyboard, trying different methods, I fixed this using some basic file I/O and some iFrames. But thankyou for the response guys! It's good to see that stackoverflow is very quick to respond!

Comment: I think I can help you, but first please help me understand exactly what you're asking.  The title of your question is about HTML entities, but those aren't mentioned anywhere in the question text.  Further, you imply that you're getting unexpected output, but the output you showed is consistent with your code.  What would help is: what's the output you /expect/ to see?  (What do "nice table" and "raw output" mean?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using external libraries like bottle you can use standard python to do so (i dont think it'll make a difference as long as your purpose is solved)

You can use the Html parser from the standard lib see 
[this page](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html)

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> print h.unescape('&pound;682m')
£682m
EDIT for Python 3: the HTMLParser module has been renamed to html.parser.

>>> import html.parser
>>> h = html.parser.HTMLParser()
>>> print(h.unescape('&pound;682m'))
£682m
```